# Windows File Sharing not working

Tags: windows-7, services

I have been using Windows File Sharing a while now on my home network. But now none of my other computers can connect. I have recently tried varies VPN service such as tunggle and Hamachi. (None of which worked, even with forwarded ports, not sure if its related)

Security Center service is not running.  I have gone into services in management tried to start it, however it tells me "Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running the same process." So I go in to properties and change the user for the service from "Local Service" to "logon user".

But that gives me Error: 1083: The executable program that this service is configured to run in does not implement the service."

I have my firewall off, and I have tried installing Comodo Firewall. Same result.

The Security Center service was set to "automatic delay", but i have since changed it to automatic.

I have tried the homegroup troubleshooter in windows, which fines nothing wrong lulz!

I have tried two routers, with the modem in bridge mode.

I have windows 7 64bit and I have updated my nic drivers

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you trying to share files inside of your network or are you enabling Windows file sharing over the Internet to remote computers? If you are sharing internally, why use a VPN solution? If you were sharing to the Internet and had your firewall off, you're probably infected.

Comment: What happens when remote computers try to connect to shares? Do you get an error?

Comment: @markm, only trying to share within my home network. I was using VPN to host a lan game. I have done the usual spyware scans

@stephen Not sure what you mean, but other computers in my house can still connect to each other perfectly.

Comment: The errors you are getting for the service starting up (Error 1083 and 1079) are for the Security Center?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just got lazy and preformed and "upgrade install" which reinstalled all my Windows Services.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup at home, Windows 7 64-Bit as the "Server" and Windows 7, Vista, XP as the clients.  My setup works just fine.

My "Server" service is running as "Local System" and starts automatically.

The only thing I had to do was create accounts on my PC that matched the accounts off of the other PCs and using the same password.  So if my laptop logs in as Steve with a password of password, I needed to create the same account with the same password on my desktop to get the sharing to work.  I also needed to use a password for my laptop account to get this to work.

Even using a VPN won't help you because fundamentally you are more than likely not authenticating correctly to the server.

Comment: Try it! I've already done by that way and it functions. Do not forget to disable all firewalls to connect at first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try [System Restore](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/systemrestore.mspx).

If that doesn't work, try [Microsoft Fix It Center](http://fixitcenter.support.microsoft.com/Portal/).